# How to disable GWT RichTextArea drag resize

Tags: java, gwt

How do I disable a GWT RichTextArea widget not to do "drag-resizing"? I just want to be set to a specific width but not removing its multi-line function.

I've tried `setSize()` but still it can be resized when dragged at the bottom-right part of it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to set max/min height and width:

```
 widget.getElement().getStyle().setProperty("maxWidth","200px");
 widget.getElement().getStyle().setProperty("maxHeight","200px");
```

Or simply you can do it with CSS 3, there is [`resize`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_resize.asp) property but it will be problem with older version of the browsers.

Answer (score 3):

You can also set its style like this:

1. In your Java class:

   ```
   yourWidgetInstance.addStyleName("yourStyleClassName");
   ```
2. In the associated CSS file:

   ```
   .yourStyleClassName {
     max-height: 75px;
     min-height: 75px;
     max-width: 150px;
     min-width: 150px;
   }
   ```